# Preventing page from refreshing aspx.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I have a aspx page like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="xxxx.aspx.cs" Inherits="xxxx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head id="Head1" runat="server">  
<title>How to use DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged event</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
<div>  
    <h2 style="color:Red">DropDownList: OnSelectedIndexChanged</h2>  
    <asp:Label   
         ID="Label1"  
         runat="server"  
         Font-Bold="true"  
         ForeColor="DodgerBlue"  
         Font-Size="Large"  
         >  
    </asp:Label>  

    <asp:DropDownList   
         ID="drop1"  
         runat="server"  
         AutoPostBack="true"  
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="GetLocationDetails"  
         BackColor="Crimson"  
         ForeColor="FloralWhite"  
        onclientselectedindexchanged="return false;"
         >  

    </asp:DropDownList>  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

The value for the dropdown list "drop1" is populated from the database from the page "xxxx.aspx.cs". When i select the value from the drop down box a function called "GetLocationDetails" is called from the aspx.cs. When i press a value from drop down box, the page is refreshed and the first value is only selected. please help out.

Comment: Show your code-behind.

Comment: Can you post your "xxxx.aspx.cs" code also?

Answer (score 1):

Bind your dropdown list in page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(!IsPostBack)
      {
           //Bind here or call method that binds dropdownlist
      }
}
```

`AutoPostBack` is set `true` which causes whole page to be posted back to server. 
If you don't track `IsPostBack` of the `page` your dropdownlist is binded again.

Answer (score 0):

your `AutoPostBack="true"` in the drop down menu causes your page to submit a request each time you change a value. and since you populate the drop down each page load, it will reset everything.

in your code behind, in page load, wrap your populating code with:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{


}
```

this will cause the drop down to be only populated on first page load and not on postbacks.